# Максимальное значение в списке словаря Python, которое стоит вторым по списку

Tags: python, python-3.x

мой код не работает: если первый индекс больше чем у других ключей списков, то выводит его в ответ

```
d = {i:[0,0] for i in range(37)}

for kk in d.values():
    kk[0]+=1
d[30][0]=0 
d[32][1]+=1676
d[30][1]+=43355


общее=max(d.values())[1]
dd = {jj:zz for jj, zz in d.items() for f in zz if f == max(d.values())[1]}


print(dd)
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Это нужно:

```
max(d.values(), key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
```

?

Comment: а минимальное? 1 по списку?

Comment: Может, min ?....

Answer (score 0):

```
max(lst[1] for lst in d.values())
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Мы можем это сделать это постепенно:

1. Сначала создаем *список из вторых элементов*:

   ```
   second_elements = [lst[1] for lst in d.values()]
   ```
2. Затем *применим функцию `max()`*
   (и / или *`min()`*, чего вам надо):

   ```
    max_of_second_elements = max(second_elements)             # или min вместо max
   ```

Теперь почти то же самое в одном шаге

- без использования временной переменной (y меня `second_elements`)
- с возможным удалением квадратных скобок (т.е. *генератор* вместо списка):

  ```
  max_of_second_elements = max(lst[1] for lst in d.values())
  ```

Answer (score 0):

С применением numpy:

```
import numpy as np      # pip install numpy

d_array = np.array([e for e in d.values()])               # Создание матрицы из списков
d_array[:,1].max()
```

Т.е. применим метод `.max()` ко второму столбцу матрицы.